# Laravel - Pass a variable with Query Builder function

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel's query builder example is it possible to pass a variable to this function:

```
$someVariable = 1;

DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($someVariable) {
            $query->where('votes', '>', $someVariable)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

It seems the function cannot access the variable outside of itself. I get an error: Undefined variable: $someVariable

Comment: " I get an error. " how about telling us what the error is?

Comment: @rtfm updated with error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use the "use" keyword after your function, for variables outside of that function. If `$someVariable` is the one you want to use, this should work.

```
$someVariable = 1;

DB::table('users')
->where('name', '=', 'John')
->orWhere(function ($query) use($someVariable) {
    $query->where('votes', '>', $someVariable)->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Superglobals 

$GLOBALS["someVariable"] = 1;
DB::table('users')
->where('name', '=', 'John')
->orWhere(function ($query) {
       $query->where('votes', '>', $GLOBALS["someVariable"])
       ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
})
->get();
```